# How to create a Select-Field from a queryset and implement it in a form

Tags: django, django-forms

i have created a simple book-app, with 3 models, Book, Author, Genre. Everything works fine and now I want to create a Select-Field for the genre. The content of the Select-Field should be a queryset from the existing genres. The Select-Field should be in a template and when I chose a genre and click the Search-Button it should list the genre and its books.
As I can't realize that I need your help for the following:

1. Where I have to generate the Select-Field and can I implement it?
2. What do I have to do in the views.py?

Here what I have done so far in forms.py:

```
class GenreSelectForm(forms.Form):
    categories = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Genre.objects.all())
```

Furthermore I created a template (genre_select.html) as follows:

```html
{% block content %}
  <h4>Searching</h4>
  <form action="" method="GET"></form>
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
{% endblock %}
```

However I don't know if this is the right way and how to implement it.

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def get_books(self):
        return Book.objects.filter(genre__name=self.name)


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    date_published = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send all the genre in the template from views like

```
 def your_view(request):

        if request.method == 'GET':
            genres = Genre.objects.all()
            context = {'genres ' : genres }
            return render(request,'genre_select.html',context)
        else: #post method
            genres = Genre.objects.all()
            genre = request.POST.get('name_of_your_select_tag')
            books = Book.objects.filter(genre=genre)
            context = {
                        'genres ' : genres,
                        'books' : books,
                      }
            return render(request,'genre_select.html',context)
```

you can write the above code in view which is rendering `genre_select.html` template. and in your template, you can write something like this

```
{% block content %}
  <h4>Searching</h4>
  <form action="" method="GET"></form>
  <select>
    {% for genre in genres %}
    <option value="{{genre.id}}"> {{genre.name}} </option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
{% endblock %}
```

and in your view, you can get the `genre_id` and show books matching with that genre. by above method you don't need to include genre field in `forms.py`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The select-field (gave it the name='selector') works fine and I can choose from all my genres. However I struggle to get the value in the view. Do I need a new view-function and is it now a post request? Can you edit your answer for a solution?
Please note in your answer it has to be "return render (request...)"

Comment: Thanks for updating. I just added  "return render(request,'genre_select.html',context)" to your if-clause and it works.